# Remove class based on elements but not others

Tags: javascript

I have these sections on this side scrolling site. And want to add a class which will change styling depending if you're on a certain section.

I'm working on this function. The top is what determines the section of the side scroller you are viewing.

The let variables and below is where it stops working. I'm trying to have it so if a nonHome ID section is clicked, for example "slide-1", then add the class 'nav-visibilty'. If they are a match "slide-2" and "slide-2" then remove said class. Am I close?

https://codepen.io/mikayp-the-styleful/pen/NWPxoXR?editors=1111

```
    setTimeout(function(){
      for (i=0; i < nonHome.length; i++ ){
        if (nonHome[i].id != nonHomeID){
          nonHome[i].classList.add("nav-visibility");
          console.log('add')
        } else{
          nonHomeID.classList.remove("nav-visibility");
            console.log('rem')
        }

      }
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, but an evident problem is that at least one of `nonHomeID.classList` and `id != nonHomeID` does not make sense. Is `nonHomeID` an ID-string, or a DOM element?

Comment: @FengyangWang I'm trying to create a check on click. I guess it doesn't really matter. nonHomeID could be a string now that you mention it. 

But I'm basically trying to create an if/else statement in this function that if the button thats selected is the element that has onclick="slideTo('slide-2')" then look for the section that has 'slide-2' as its id and add the class to that section. 

If that doesnt make sense I can reword it.

Comment: Doing this with `setTimeout` is not generally the right way. You should put the code in the click handler that sets `nonHomeID`.

Comment: @Barmar so like a different function?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not totally clear on the behavior that you want, but there are two errors in the code that can be fixed:

- It seems like you are always using `'slide-2'` instead of the `slideId` in your event handler.
- As mentioned in a comment, `nonHomeID` is being used incorrectly in your comparison (it is either a string or an element, but you are using it as if it was a string in the `if` condition, and as the element in the `else` branch.) Here I have kept it as an element and renamed it for clarity.

Fixing these errors results in code that applies the `nav-visibility` class to all slides except the one selected by the button. Is that the desired behavior?

```
  let nonHome = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-container section");
  let nonHomeSelected = document.getElementById(slideId);

  var i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < nonHome.length; i++) {
      if (nonHome[i] != nonHomeSelected) {
        nonHome[i].classList.add("nav-visibility");
        console.log("add");
      } else {
        nonHome[i].classList.remove("nav-visibility");
        console.log("rem");
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Edit to add: If the goal is to add `nav-visibility` to all only the specific `slideId`, you should not be adding in a loop, i.e. you need to pull your check for whether the slide is Home outside the loop. There are conceptually two steps here: remove the class from all elements that are no longer to have it, then add the class to the element that needs it.

```
let slideToAddVisibilityTo = document.getElementById(slideId)
let homeSlide = document.getElementById('slide-2')
let allSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-container section")

for (let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; ++i)
    allSlides[i].classList.remove('nav-visiblity')

if (slideToAddVisibilityTo != homeSlide)
    slideToAddVisibilityTo.classList.add('nav-visibility')
```

Comment: Why  compare IDs instead of just comparing the elements themselves? `if (nonHome[i] != nonHomeSelected)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the code. It's in the right direction but i want the check to be if it's the 'slide-2' function on click then add, but if not then remove.

Comment: Your code does not use `slideId` at all after animating it. Do you intend to only run the rest of the function if `slideId` is `'slide-2'`?

Comment: Are you looking at the codeped I posted? Just wanna make sure. 

Maybe explaining more will help. It's a side scrolling site with 5 sections. The nonHome let is all of those sections with 'slide-#' and there's css thats implements if it's any one but id='slide-2'. 

So it's the Home section, '#slide-2', that does not need the .nav-visibility class if that slide is in focus on click. Hence the slide.scrollIntoView. BUT if its any other section that's brought into view then add .nav-visibility to those sections. 

Hopefully that gives context and I'm on the right track.

Comment: Hi @MPortman, sorry about the continued confusion. I did see your coderpad but I still do not understand what the `slideId` is supposed to mean. Is the purpose of the buttons to focus a specific section? That is, if user clicks button for `slide-1`, add nav-visibility to `#slide-1` and remove it from other slides? Currently your code is not doing this; it is always adding `.nav-visibility` to all slides except `slide-2`.

Comment: Please see my new edit and let me know if this is closer to your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide them all, then show the clicked one:

```
function showSection(id) {
  var sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
  for(var i=0; i<sections.length; i++) sections[i].classList.remove("nav-visibility");

  var current = document.getElementById(id);
  current.classList.add("nav-visibility");

}
```

Example: showSection("foo") will remove nav-visibility from all sections, then add it to the section with id foo.

Comment: And then if/when it goes to the section with ID of slide-2 it needs to hide again.